# Why doesn`t C++ to_string function support char and unsigned char type?

Tags: c++

On [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), it says that the `to_string` function could work in the following ways. Why isn't there `char` and `unsigned char` type?

```
to_string(int value);
to_string(long value);
to_string(long long value);
to_string(unsigned value);
to_string(unsigned long value);
to_string(unsigned long long value);
to_string(float value);
to_string(double value);
to_string(long double value);
```

Comment: Because a `char` can be already converted to `std::string` without the use of `std::to_string`? That is there is already the constructor  `basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch,
const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );`. Basically, **you don't need a `char` overload of `to_string`**.

Comment: What would you want it to do with `char` and `unsigned char`, and, presumably also with `signed char` (these 3 are distinct types)?

Comment: It seems that I interpreted the question differently than others did. So it is important that you clarify: What do you expect e.g. `std::to_string('a')` to produce? Do you expect it to produce a string with contents `a` or a string with contents `97`?

Answer (score 6):

> Why there isn`t char and unsigned char type?

Because there is already a `std::string` constructor `std::string::string(size_type, char)` that can take a `char`. In particular, from [`basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
//-----------------------------vvvvv------------------->character type parameter
basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This means that instead of using `to_string`, we can just use

```
std::string str(1, 'c');
```

that will use the above constructor.

Basically, we don't need an overload of `to_string` for `char` as `std::string` already have the constructor available for it.

Comment: I think the advantage should be to use as a generic function, similar to C# ToString() method. Even the result on std::string should be definable (of course, there might be an issue about unused copy), but it feels weird to use different method for char or int.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with ambiguity. By applying `to_string` to character 'a'(=97) do you want to get string "a" or string "97"?

If you want to get "a" then just use one of the constructors of the string. If you want "97" then apply `to_string` after casting the character to an `int` or some other integer type.

Comment: `std::to_string('a')` already produces `97`. No casting required.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of passing a `char` or `unsigned char` to `std::to_string` is already what would be expected. Adding overloads will not change anything.

In principle just an overload for `signed long long` and `unsigned long long` would be sufficient to cover all integer types, since every integer type can be converted to one of these without the value being affected. Both of these overloads are required because `unsigned long long` wouldn't be able to take negative values correctly and `signed long long` is not able to represent the largest values that `unsigned long long can`.

However, because the overload rules in C++ do not consider converting e.g. `int` to `signed long long` any better or worse than `int` to `unsigned long long`, you wouldn't be able to pass e.g. an `int` directly to the function if *only* these two overloads were present. The call would be ambiguous:

```
void f(unsigned long long) {}
void f(signed long long) {}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    f(x); // fails due to ambiguity
}
```

You need to add an overload for `int`, `unsigned int`, etc. as well:

```
void f(unsigned long long) {}
void f(signed long) {}
void f(unsigned long long) {}
void f(signed long) {}
void f(unsigned int) {}
void f(signed int) {}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    f(x); // ok, prefers f(signed int) without conversion
}
```

However, no overloads for `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char`, `signed short` and `unsigned short` are required, because the C++ overload rules do consider conversions from these types to integral types with higher rank (i.e. `int` and larger) differently.

A conversion from one of these types to `int`, if `int` is able to represent all of their values, or `unsigned int` otherwise, is a so-called *integral promotion* and is considered better than any other conversion to any of the other integral type. So there will be no ambiguity in overload resolution even if there are no specific overloads for these types. They will always choose the `int` or `unsigned int` overload and their values will be represented faithfully.

```
void f(unsigned long long) {}
void f(signed long) {}
void f(unsigned long long) {}
void f(signed long) {}
void f(unsigned int) {}
void f(signed int) {}

int main() {
    char x = 0;
    f(x); // ok, chooses f(signed int) with integral promotion instead of integral conversion
}
```